# how to find lowest common ancestor of a nary tree?

Tags: algorithm, tree

Is there a way without using extra space to find LCA of nary tree.
I did it using a string saving the preorder of both the nodes and finding common prefix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If nodes "know" their depth - or you're willing to allow the space to compute the depth of your nodes, you can back up from the lower node to the same depth of the higher node, and then go up one level at a time until they meet.

Depends on what "extra space" means in this context.  You can do it with one integer - the difference in depths of the two nodes.  Is that too much space?

Another possibility is given you don't have a parent pointer, you can use pointer reversal - every time you traverse a pointer, remember the location from which you came, remember the pointer you will next traverse, and then just before the next pointer traversal, replace that pointer with the back pointer.  You have to reverse this when going up the tree to restore it.  This takes the space of one pointer as a temporary.  And another integer to keep the depth as you work your way down and up.  Do this synchronously for the two nodes you seek, so that you can work your way back up from the lower one until you're at the same height in both traversals, and then work back up from both until you're at the common node.  This takes three extra pieces of memory - one for each of the current depths, one for the temporary used during a pointer reversal.  Very space efficient.  Is it worth it?

Comment: I don't have a parent pointer , neither i have a depth field in node.

Comment: So you have an nary search tree, not just an nary tree?  Else you can't know the path to construct the strings.  You can compute the depth when you work your way down.  But without a parent pointer, you have the choice of reversing pointers as you traverse, or following the approach given by wildplasser.

Comment: I can by doing depth first traversal, i can save the path from root to both the nodes in two seperate strings and then take common prefix's last character. That will be the answer but here i am using two strings i.e extra space.

Comment: If by depth first traversal, you mean recursive, depth-first search, considering every leaf until you find a match, then the stack required for backtracking is actually more memory than the string you're building...

Answer (score 3):

Go back and do it for a binary tree. If you can do it for a binary tree you can do it for an n-ary tree.

Here's [a link to LCA in a binary tree](http://www.fusu.us/2013/06/p2-lowest-common-ancestor-in-binary-tree.html):

And here's how it looks after converting it to a n-ary tree LCA:

```java
  public class LCA {

    public static <V> Node<V> 
                lowestCommonAncestor(Node<V> argRoot, Node<V> a, Node<V> b) {

      if (argRoot == null) {
        return null;
      }

      if (argRoot.equals(a) || argRoot.equals(b)) {
        // if at least one matched, no need to continue
        // this is the LCA for this root
        return argRoot;
      }

      Iterator<Node<V>> it = argRoot.childIterator();
      // nr of branches that a or b are on, 
      // could be max 2 (considering unique nodes)
      int i = 0; 
      Node<V> lastFoundLCA = null;
      while (it.hasNext()) {
        Node<V> node = lowestCommonAncestor(it.next(), a, b);
        if (node != null) {
          lastFoundLCA = node;
          i++ ;
        }
        if (i >= 2) {
          return argRoot;
        }
      }

      return lastFoundLCA;
    }

  }
```

Comment: Great modification. But this solution assume that both nodes exist in the tree, if this is not the case, it will fail in some situations.

Answer (score 0):

Do a synchronous walk to both the nodes.

- Start with LCA=root;
- loop:
- find the step to take for A and the step for B
- if these are equal { LCA= the step; decend A; descend B; goto loop; }
- done: LCA now contains the lca for A and B

Pseudocode in C:

```
struct node {
        struct node *offspring[1234];
        int payload;
        };

        /* compare function returning the slot in which this should be found/placed */
int find_index (struct node *par, struct node *this);

struct node *lca(struct node *root, struct node *one, struct node *two)
{
struct node *lca;
int idx1,idx2;

for (lca=root; lca; lca=lca->offspring[idx1] ) {
    idx1 = find_index(lca, one);
    idx2 = find_index(lca, two);
    if (idx1 != idx2 || idx1 < 0) break;
    if (lca->offspring[idx1] == NULL) break;
    }
return lca;
}
```

Comment: This assumes find_index can be implemented without building the pre-order traversal.  If this is not a search tree, but just an nary tree, how is this done?

Comment: Well, IMHO that is basically the same problem as you building up two strings consisting of the paths to A and B. How did you obtain the strings, if the tree was not searchable ?

Comment: Given the nodes, you can walk the path back to the root, pre-pending to the string at each step.  This is tagged algorithm, with no language, so I'm assuming edges can be traversed in either direction.